# How to remove comma from a number being dynamically inserted in the value of a key in the properties file / resource bundle?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, number-formatting, resourcebundle

I am using Struts 2. I have a JSP. It has this code:

```
<span class="helpMessage">
    <s:text name="page.key">
        <s:param value="%{request.id}" />
    </s:text>
</span>
```

`request` object is a member of my action class, and `id` is a property of the `request` object. `id` is of the type `int`.

In my properties file I have written the following text:

```
page.key=The request ID is {0}
```

My request id is a 6 digit number. Whenever it is displayed on the jsp it is displayed with a comma, eg: 765,239. I want it to be displayed without a comma, like this: 765239. I think the comma is being displayed because the data type of the `id` is int.

If I convert it to a `string` by writing the code below then the comma is not displayed.

```
<s:param value="%{request.id.toString()}" />
```

I want to know if instead of the above modification in the JSP can I do some modification in the properties file/resource bundle, like inserting a number format, to remove the comma in the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are looking for setting the number format..
[here is the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/formatting-dates-and-numbers.html) from Struts 2 regarding this.

`format.number = {0} # i think this should do`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the link, modifying the key value in the properties file to the below mentioned value helped me get rid of the comma without modifying the JSP!! 
`page.key=The request ID is {0,number,#}`